# Double Slit Experiment with Protons

Tags: double-slit-experiment, protons

Has the double slit experiment been executed with a proton beam? Electrons and photons seem to get all the attention.  What about a particle with positive charge, and one said to be composed of multiple charged entities?

Comment: Neutrons diffract/scatter just fine (even in a double-slit experiment), so that takes care of the last bit.

Comment: Have you seen this website: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-slit_experiment

Comment: I will not that for the neutrons above to diffract one has to get them to pretty low energies so their de Broglie wavelength is compatible with diffraction from macroscopic slits. in Rev. Mod. Physics 60(4) 1988, the used "very cold" neutrons with a wavelength of 1.5 to 3 nanometers. (2 nm is about 0.2 meV in energy). With protons it will be really hard to overcome stray charge interactions swamping any slit diffraction. Since electrons are much lighter, they can be made to diffract just fine.

Comment: When talking about double slit experiment with protons, did you calculate the de Broglie wave length, and find out what slits you could use? and what speed  of the p?

Comment: How about a beam of 1 ton elephants?  Had that problem on a test years (50) ago.

Comment: I checked the suggested Wikipedia page. The single mention of protons was to compare  sizes with buckyballs, the latter having been double-slitted.  It's seems increasingly odd that protons were not featured.